# Mac OSX MongoDB failed to set up sockets during startup

Tags: macos, mongodb

My MongoDB on the mac suddenly cound not be started.  These are the messages:

```
2016-10-24T11:13:04.080-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=365 port=27017 dbpath=/Users/user1/mongodb/data/db 64-bit host=Mac1.attlocal.net
2016-10-24T11:13:04.081-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.6
2016-10-24T11:13:04.081-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25
2016-10-24T11:13:04.081-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-10-24T11:13:04.081-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-10-24T11:13:04.081-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-10-24T11:13:04.081-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-10-24T11:13:04.081-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-10-24T11:13:04.081-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "mongod.conf", storage: { dbPath: "/Users/user1/mongodb/data/db" } }
2016-10-24T11:13:04.082-0500 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:1 Operation not permitted for socket: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2016-10-24T11:13:04.082-0500 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2016-10-24T11:13:04.083-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

I tried this:

```
Mac1:mongodb user1$ ls -ld /tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Feb 23  2016 /tmp -> private/tmp
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Does it have permission to write on `/Users/user1/mongodb/data/db`? Does this folder exist?

Comment: Yes, db is there.  Here are the permissions if I do ls -ld db:  drwxrwxrwx  26 user1  staff  884 Oct 14 16:22 db

Comment: Are you trying to start mongod as "user1", or as root?

Comment: @andresk:  I start mongodb as user1.  User1 is Admin.

Comment: When I tried to copy a test file to this /tmp directory, I got this "Operation not permitted".  It seemed this is the cause of the issue.  Any idea how to allow this tmp directory to read and write?

Answer (score 0):

As in turned out earlier in the day, my machine did a automatically security updated for OS X El Capitan 2016-002.  This update changed the flag for /tmp label and /private/tmp folder to "restricted".  As such nothing can be created in that location (see my comment above).

To fix this:

1. Reboot your Mac into safe mode
2. goto Terminal and issue: csrutil disable
3. Reboot your Mac to normal mode
4. Change restricted flag to nonrestricted for that location.  In Terminal: sudo chflags norestricted /private/tmp.  And sudo chflags norestricted /tmp  (not sure if this one is needed)
5. Change permissions as well if needed: sudo chmod 1777 /tmp and sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp
6. Reboot to safe mode again, and do a csrutil enable back

That solved my problem.